# fork() in multi-thread program

Tags: c, multithreading, fork, posix

I have some problems with forks in multithreading, here is the code

```
node_visited *visited, *it;


sem_t visited_q, elements;


char mode;

int count = 0;


int nthreads;


void *work_1 (void* args){

    int linf, i, lsup, status;
    linf = (int)args;
    char *path, buff[256];
    pid_t pid;
    linf = linf * (count/nthreads);

    lsup = linf  + (count/nthreads);
    //printf("%d\n",count );
    printf("Soy el hilo %d limite inferior: %d limite superior: %d numero de threads: %d numero de elementos: %d\n", (int) args, linf, lsup, nthreads, count);



    if (mode == 'e') {

   int j,fd[2];

        for (j = linf; j < lsup; j++) {


            pipe(fd);
            pid = fork();

            if (pid == 0) {

                //fflush(stdout);
                dup2(fd[1], STDOUT_FILENO);
                //printf("Antes del execl()\n");

        //sem_wait(&visited_q);
                execl("md5","md5", visited[j].path, NULL);
        //sem_post(&visited_q);

            } else if (pid > 0) {

                wait(NULL);
                dup2(fd[0], 0);
                scanf("%s",buff);
        //sem_wait(&visited_q);
                strcpy(visited[j].hashstr, buff);
        printf("%s\n",visited[j].hashstr );
        //sem_post(&visited_q);
            }
        }

    } else if (mode == 'l') {
        for (i = linf; i < lsup; i++) {
            status = MDFile ( visited[i].path, visited[i].hashstr);
        }
    }

}
```

The program have to visit all files in a directory given by instruction line arguments (I read it with getopt) then I have to get the md5 hash using threads, there is the problem, when call fork(), with 1,2 and 3 threads and a directory with 25 files, works fine, but when the number of threads is greater than 3, the program seems to be in a deadlock, infinite wait or some problem, I don't know what to do.

Comment: Maybe add some print statements to better track down the issue? Have you tried using a debugger to see where it hangs?

Comment: Yes, I have used gdb, and seems to only a thread survive or the program fall into a deadlock

Comment: it hangs at the void* work_1(void* args), at the wait(NULL); instruction

Comment: Avoid writing down a lot of code lines here. Try to explain the problem and where it occurs in order to receive better answers :)

Comment: Next time, try to *isolate* the problem into smallest possible working piece of code demonstrating your problem. If it's too long, most people won't bother to read it at all. And when you'll try to make it shorter, then you'll often find out what's wrong by yourself, just because you will be able to see it clearly.

Comment: Thanks! you're right, the next time I will do that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
else if (pid > 0) {
    ...
    dup2(fd[0], 0);
    scanf("%s",buff);
```

Don't dup the pipe to file descriptor 0. You're doing this in the parent process, so all of your threads are fighting over whose pipe gets to be stdin. Just read from the original pipe:

```
    FILE *pipe = fdopen(fd[0], "r");
    fscanf(pipe, "%s", buff);
    fclose(pipe);
```

Disclaimer: My `c` is a little rusty.

Also, when you call `wait(NULL)` in the parent, it will return when *any* child finishes, not just the child that the specific thread just started. You ought to call `waitpid()` here instead with the PID of a specific child here.

Comment: Oh thanks, in that case, I need to change the dup2(f[1],STDOUT_FILENO)?

Comment: You can dup in the child, and it's a reasonable thing to do here. Each process has its own set of file descriptors, so changes in one child won't affect the parent or the other children. But all of the threads in the parent are sharing single set of fds.

Comment: Ok, I will try this and then tell what happened

Comment: Well I just remove the dup2(...) instruction in the parent piece of code and work FINE for now! thanks a lot. About the wait(NULL), again, you have reason haha I will change that too!